# Conference paper with an ISBN

Tags: publications, google-scholar, persistent-identifiers

Is an ISBN a sign of prestigious publishing?

Will the conference paper with ISBN appea in Google scholar, ResearchGate and orcid?

Is ARICBET CONFFERENCE PRESTUGIOUS?

Comment: ISBN is for books, not papers. How would such a number be assigned?

Answer (score 3):

No, ISBN is for identification purposes. It has no intrinsic value other than as a means of distinguishing (usually) books. It awards no "prestige". If a conference publishes its proceedings then the proceedings would likely have an ISBN and you can search for the volume by that alone. But the individual paper wouldn't have an individual ISBN.

Whether the paper appears in indexes is a completely separate matter, but conference papers in some fields often do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So , how should I add it in this case to google scholar or researchgate?

Answer (score 1):

As its name suggests (International Standard **Book** Number) and Buffy also said, ISBN are normally used for books only. Journal papers and conference papers are usually given [a DOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) instead which serves the same purpose: providing the document in question with a unique digital ID that makes it easier to find.

As to the second part of your question: nothing gets added to *Researchgate* automatically, you (or one of the other authors) will have to add it to your account yourself. *Orcid* ususally (but not always!) updates automatically, if you provided the publisher / the conference with your orcid ID when submitting the paper. If you didn't, there is a high chance of having it to do yourself. *Google scholar* also mostly (but not always) updates automatically. In doubt, check and add manually if necessary.